# New Xcode project with Git show warning

Tags: xcode, git

I have set a new test project to see how to use git, so I have checked GIT when creating the project. Then I have pressed on the create button and got a  weird warning (attached).

Then I have opened the project and all the files were marked with A (They shouldn't) as git [image]

should commit them on the project creation.

Any idea how to configure a user for git?

I have also tried to open terminal and write the line from the error with my email. it didn't worked.

I use xcode 4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the following two commands from the terminal should make sure you won't get this error in the future:

```
git config --global user.email "IOS.DEV@mail.com"
git config --global user.name "IOS DEV"
```

Comment: You are right, it worked but now I can't see the M/A in the navigator although I can see the .git in the file folder